# using two light switches to control only a GFI (No light involved)

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 3 way light switch on the deck of my swimming pool and another under my deck. I want to control only the GFI (No lights, fans or or anything else involved). 
In power has 3 wires: a Black, white and Ground. And I have 4 wires to control the switches and the GFI. A Black, white, Red and a Ground. Only one of the 3 way light switches is in the same box as the GFI under my deck. The other light switch on the Deck. How do I connect all the wiring to control the GFI?
Thank You 
Bob

Comment: What did the switches formerly control? You should be able to simply move the two wires that ran to the previous load to the *line* side of your GFCI outlet.

Comment: Brand new wiring. Just added this electrical to control my pool pump.

Comment: Wouldn't one normally figure out how they were going to hook it all up before running the wire?  Wiring it should be no different than a 3 way light.  Just replace light fixture with load side of GFI in any diagram.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Thanks Grant, you got it correct. It works. I really appreciate your help buddy!!!

Answer (score 1):

Then from your in power connect the bare ground to the ground terminal of the GFI. Connect the white wire to the GFI. The black wire connects (wire nut) to the other black wire going to the 3 way switch on the deck. The red and white wires from the deck go to the traveler terminals of the 3 way switches (same on both switches). At the GFI add a black wire from it to the common terminal of the 3 way. Add a bare wire between the GFI ground and the 3 way ground terminal. On the deck 3 way connect the black wire to the common terminal. Connect the bare ground to the ground terminal of the switch.

Comment: Not all GFCIs auto-trip when powered off. I have occasional power outages at my house and nine of the GFCI outlets need to be reset.

Comment: I think most newer GFCI receptacles automatically trip when power is lost, but I can't remember if that's a requirement or a feature.